# Joomla jdatabase не хочет отправлять в базу текст, с цифрами все в порядке

Tags: virtuemart, joomla, mysql, sql

Привет всем, такая проблема:

Есть код:

```
     $db2 = JFactory::getDbo();
     $db2->setQuery('update #__virtuemart_orders set '.$row.' =' .$Data.' where virtuemart_order_id='.$virtuemart_order_id);
     $db2->query();
```

Если записывать в базу числа, то все в порядке, а если буквы и числа или просто буквы, то ничего не записывает. В базе стоит тип данных varchar, при выполнении запроса через phpmyadmin все отлично работает.

Как быть?

Comment: как же меня бесят эти джумловские названия JFactoryDatabsMySQL::getDboFromHrenZnaetOtkyda

Answer (score 1):

```
    $db2 = JFactory::getDbo();
    $db2->setQuery('update `#__virtuemart_orders` set '.$db->quoteName($row).' = '.$db->quote($Data).' where `virtuemart_order_id` = '.$db->quote($virtuemart_order_id));
    $db2->execute(); // Joomla 3
    $db2->query(); // Joomla old
```